# Front derailleur takes 6 clicks to shift gears, instead of 3

Tags: derailleur, gears, handlebars, adjustment

I've just stripped all cables and chain from a badly kept bicycle and replaced them.

I've correctly adjusted the rear derailleur and it works great.

However, front derailleur which only has 3 gears isn't working as expected.

It takes 2-3 steps on the gear to actually change 1 gears.
The range seems to be 1-6, instead of 3.

The gear is the type that is round, circular next to the handles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is normal. The procedure is called trimming.

It allows you to move the front derailleur cage a bit to prevent the derailleur cage rubbing on the chain due to the changing angle of the chain when shifting in the rear.

Comment: There is no rubbing on chain. The problem is front gear has 3 steps. My gear shifter thing, on the handle, does 6 steps. My problem is with that.

Comment: Yes, that's normal. The extra steps are there for accounting for the case where the derailleur cage may rub.

Comment: Thank you. I'd like to accept your answer but I think it better be edited a little with this information. Or do you recon "trimming" is the all and only answer there is?

Comment: That is what trimming means.